# "Code Sign error: No unexpired provisioning profiles found that contain any of the keychain's signing certificates"

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I have a problem with all my new projects. If I try to "Archive" to submit to app store I'm getting this error `"Code Sign error: No unexpired provisioning profiles found that contain any of the keychain's signing certificates"`. But if I try to archive any of my old projects, they works just fine. I notice the code sign options are different in both projects:

Working project:

[image]

This is the NOT WORKING code sign options:

[image]

My question for you guys is that, why the difference or how can I make my project work and get the right options for code sign.

I'll really appreciate all your help.

Comment: The computer is the same?

Comment: is the same computer. Both projects are open at the same time.

Comment: CHECK THE BUNDLE IDENTIFIER YOU HAVE GIVEN

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While Selecting a Provisioning profile(Developer or distribution) make sure you choose the one that matches the bundle identifier you have entered in your target's summary.

May be you have not added the right bundle identifier. Just check..

**EDIT:** check out the image in summary. you have to enter the bundle identifier of the provisioning profile you want to use. I hope you are aware that every provisioning has a bundle identifier. Example com.yourCompany.something

Make sure that the identifier in your target's summary(refer image) and the identifier of the distribution profile match when you choose a distribution profile.

[image]

Comment: the actual bundle that match the bundle of my project "profile doesn't match bundle identifier. But I don't understand why.